# PHP Sessions not passing to different pages (basic)

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass a variable from (register.php)  to (submit.php) and finally to (yes.php) - Please note that I have included the 'session_start();' in each page as an 'include' on the main php page.

register.php - 1

```
<div id = "content">
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Username*:<br>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
                Email Address*:<br>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
                Telephone Number*:<br>
                <input type="text" name="telephone">
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
                Telephone Again*: <br>
                <input type="text" name="telephoneagain">
                <br>
                </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="submit">

            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</header>
```

This is a very basic registration form.
It then gets sent to

submit.php - 2

```
 <?php
<div id = "content">
<div id = "feature">
Your username is: <?php echo $_POST['username']; ?> <br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> <br>
Your telephone number is: <?php echo $_POST['telephone']; ?> <br>
Just to confirm your telephone number: <?php echo $_POST['telephoneagain']; ?>
<br> 
<br>
</div>
<div id = "validation">
Is this correct? <br>
<li> <a href="yes.php"> Yes </a> </li> 
<li> <a href="register.php"> No </a> </li>
<?php
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['telephone'] = $telephone;
$_SESSION['telephoneagain'] = $telephoneagain;
?>
</div>
</header>
```

Again fairly basic, ignore lack of validation. So here, I can echo out the username from what was entered on register.php. I then click 'yes' to indicate that the information is correct.

yes.php - 3

```
<?php
$_POST['username'];
?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, telephone, telephoneagain)
VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$telephone', '$telephoneagain')";
?>
```

The problem here is that the variables do not pass from the previous page and therefore the page cannot find them.

People are asking if I have the session_start() on the last page, here is the full code

This is for yes.php - 3

```
 <?php
    include 'includes/yes/yeshead.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesheader.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yescontent.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesnav.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesfooter.php';
    include 'core/init.php'; ?>
```

init.php contains the session_start();

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);

require 'core/database/connect.php';
require 'core/users.php';

$current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file = end($current_file);
$errors = array();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the file with `session_start()` is being included? If the file that starts your session is required for the rest to function you should think about using `require()` rather than `include()`.

Comment: After writing into `$_SESSION` try invoking `session_write_close()`...

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? No cookies = no session – unless you pass the session ID manually.

Comment: You saying `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` but where do you get `$username` ? In this case you will get `empty` value. Define `$username=$_POST['username']` before u assign variables to a session.

Comment: Alex in 'Submit.php' the information appears when I echo it out, there is an error between 'submit.php' and 'yes.php'

Comment: What it seems to appear in `submit.php` is the `echo`'s you have `$_POST`-ed not the sessions, try `print_r($_SESSION)` i don't think you will get any values.

Comment: Alex: I entered 'r' for all the form boxes and used 'print_r($_SESSION)'                 Array ( [username] => r [email] => r [telephone] => r [telephoneagain] => r [] => username )

Comment: Interesting. @alex after using the print function on 'yes.php' the variables 'r' have been passed over but the PHP does not pick them up?? Array ( [username] => r [email] => r [telephone] => r [telephoneagain] => r [] => username ) Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/name/public_html/name/name/yes/yescontent.php on line 4

Comment: @AllahuAkbar this `[] => username` should be `[username] => some value` look somewhere if you forget any `$` in your vars. (I will suggest make a more clean code.)

Comment: Alex I have done something, and the errors are now gone... I am assuming the PHP is picking up the values now but refuses to write them into the db. I'll fix this on my own time, I have no idea who I should give the points to

Comment: @AllahuAkbar glad you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very kind Alex helped me solve this problem. I would give him the answer point but he posted comments so this will have to suffice

Answer (score 0):

Helo, try in submit.php:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];
$_SESSION['telephoneagain'] =$_POST['telephoneagain'];
```

and in yes.php:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$telephoneagain =$_POST['telephoneagain'];
```

Comment: This would make sense. **Unless** the OP is using `register_globals` which is BAD BAD BAD...

Comment: :D hahah glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Before al the code related to sessions, use `session_start();`.

You are including files related to do things with sessions and after that you include a file that includes `session_start();`. Include the file that includes `session_start();` first.

So use this in yes.php:

```
 <?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/yes/yeshead.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesheader.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yescontent.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesnav.php';
          include 'includes/yes/yesfooter.php';
     ?>
```

So make sure you add `session_start();` in each code that uses sessions, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have tried entering session_start(); in the 'yes.php' manually to see if that was causing the error but the PHP picks up on the session_start(); already included in init.php and just ignores it and still gives me the indefined index error

Comment: Undefined index means basically that the variable doesn't exists.

Comment: I see, it exists in 'submit.php' upon echoing the information they appear so it must be between 'submit.php' and 'yes.php'